# Why the where clause is not working on sharepointsearch?

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, full-text-search

```
StringBuilder xmlString = new StringBuilder(
    "<QueryPacket xmlns='urn:Microsoft.Search.Query'>"
    + "<Query><SupportedFormats><Format revision='1'> urn:Microsoft.Search.Response.Document:Document"
    + "</Format></SupportedFormats><Context>"
    + " <QueryText language='en-US' type='FQL'>");

// this adds the search free form text 
xmlString.Append("Earth");
query.Append(
    "</QueryText></Context>"
    + "<Properties>"
    + "<Property name='Name'/>"
    + "<Property name='Department' />"
    + "<Property name='Property1' />"                
    + "<Property name='Property2' />"
    + "<Property name='Property3' />"
    + "<Property name='Property4' />"
    + "<Property name='Property5' />"
    + "</Properties>"
    + "<Where>"
    + "<IsNotNull><FieldRef Name='Name'></FieldRef></IsNotNull>"
    + "<And><IsNotNull><FieldRef Name='Property1'></FieldRef></IsNotNull></And>"
    + "</Where>"                                       
    + "</Query></QueryPacket>"
);

QueryServiceSoapClient.QueryEx(query)
```

I am getting data with the null/empty value on Name and Property1 column.
Why where is not working?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your where clause is not properly formatted as @Damith suggested. Why dont you build your query using [FAST Search for Sharepoint MOSS 2010 Query Tool](http://fastforsharepoint.codeplex.com/). Its really quick and efficient way to work on this kind of tasks.

Comment: I downloaded this tool and able to get records but the issue is still exist. <IsNotNull><FieldRef Name='WireAuthorLastName' /></IsNotNull>
also not working in filtering Null or empty data on WireAuthorLastName column.

Comment: Is this property columns (property1, property2...etc) are crawled proeprties? did you do full crawl after adding it?

Comment: No property1 and property2 was an example in my query (Just for explanation that IsNotNull is not working for any property)..
I mean to say if if use
<IsNotNull><FieldRef Name='WireAuthorLastName' /></IsNotNull> this will still returning data having blank/null in WireAuthorLastName column.

Comment: as @john suggested in his answer, your KQL query is not proper. You need to build correct query. By using fast search tool you can build and execute queries and use them in your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
+ "<And><IsNotNull><FieldRef Name='Property1'></FieldRef>"+"</IsNotNull>And>"
```

In this line after `IsNotNull` you missing `</` so the line should be

```
+ "<And><IsNotNull><FieldRef Name='Property1'></FieldRef>"+"</IsNotNull></And>"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you've got the `<and>` clause sitting in the wrong place.

It should look like this:

```
 <Where>
    <And>
        <IsNotNull>
            <FieldRef Name='Name'>
            </FieldRef>
         </IsNotNull>
         <IsNotNull>
             <FieldRef Name='Property1'></FieldRef>
         </IsNotNull>
    </And>
</Where>
```

It's a weird place to have to put the and clause, I know, but that's how CAML works. I strongly recommend using a program such as [CAMLQueryHelper](http://spcamlqueryhelper.codeplex.com/) if you're going to use CAML instead of Linq.